# How to create the Dialog Lookup MultiSelect from BaseEnum?

Tags: dialog, axapta, lookup, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to add in my *DialogField* a MultiSelect Lookup.
The values show aren't from record table (like Custom Account...), but they come from a *BaseEnum*.

I want to select more than one value from lookup:

[image: MultiSelectLookup]

For example, the user can choose at the same time *Planned* and *Pais*.
My current code is this:

My class `extends RunBaseBatch`, in

```
public Object dialog()
{
    DialogRunbase dialog = super();
    ;
    dlgMultiSelect= dialog.addFieldValue(enumStr(SubledgerJournalEntryType),"","Select MULTIPLE VALUES","Select MULTIPLE VALUES");
    return dialog;
}
```

How can allow Multi Select lookup?

If it can not possible, there is other way for multiple lookup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feel free to use this test class for inspiration:

```
class StackOverflowTestDialog extends RunBase
{
    DialogRunbase           dlg;
    FormBuildStringControl  formBuildCtrl;

    SysLookupMultiSelectCtrl sysLookupMultiSelectCtrl;
}

static void main(Args _args)
{
    StackOverflowTestDialog testDialog = new StackOverflowTestDialog();

    if (testDialog.prompt())
    {
        testDialog.run();
    }
}

public Object dialog()
{
    DialogGroup         dlgGrp;
    FormBuildControl    grpCtrl;

    dlg     = super();
    dlgGrp  = dlg.addGroup();
    grpCtrl = dlg.formBuildDesign().control(dlgGrp.formBuildGroup().id());

    formBuildCtrl = grpCtrl.addControl(FormControlType::String, identifierstr(ctrlTypes));
    formBuildCtrl.label("@SYS329959");

    return dlg;

}

public void dialogPostRun(DialogRunbase _dialog)
{
    CFMEnumLookupTmp        lookupTmp;
    FormRun                 formRun;
    Query                   q;
    QueryRun                qr;
    QueryBuildDataSource    qbds;
    DictEnum                dictEnum;
    int                     i;

    super(dlg);

    formRun = _dialog.dialogForm().formRun();

    if (formRun)
    {
        //Fill in temporary table with enum values
        dictEnum = new DictEnum(enumNum(SubledgerJournalEntryType));
        for (i = 0; i < dictEnum.values(); i++)
        {
            lookupTmp.EnumValueLabelText = dictEnum.index2Label(i);
            lookupTmp.insert();
        }

        //Prepare a queryRun to work with the temporary table
        q = new Query();
        qbds = q.addDataSource(tableNum(CFMEnumLookupTmp));
        qbds.addSelectionField(fieldNum(CFMEnumLookupTmp, EnumValueLabelText));
        qr = new QueryRun(q);
        qr.setCursor(lookupTmp);        

        //Multi-select control framework class
        sysLookupMultiSelectCtrl = SysLookupMultiSelectCtrl::constructWithQueryRun(
            formRun,
            formRun.design().control(formBuildCtrl.id()),
            qr,
            true,
            [tableNum(CFMEnumLookupTmp), fieldNum(CFMEnumLookupTmp, EnumValueLabelText)]
    );
    }
}

public boolean getFromDialog()
{
    if (sysLookupMultiSelectCtrl)
    {
        info('Result: ' + con2Str(sysLookupMultiSelectCtrl.getSelectedFieldValues()));
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @10p. Right answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty extensively covered with many different methods, so you'll need to start with some searching/research.

You can do some stuff dynamically, but your best bet is to probably use a temp table + query + `SysLookupMultiSelect*`.

If you have more code to provide of attempts, we can respond to specific code questions.

See some links:

- https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/dynamics101trainingcenterax/archive/2014/11/06/using-multi-select-lookup-control-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012
- https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/252243
- https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/p/160754/402664

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny . I appreciated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, variable for multiselect value sholud NOT be enum:

1. enum keep only ONE value from base enum.
2. a multiselect returns one or MORE values from lookup

Second, If you want to process with several elements of a enum, you should decide:

- processing for label or enumValue?
- what langauge is for a label?
- how another methods does to show a enum multivalue to a user? (text messages, forms, reports, BI/OLAP and other)

---

I'm sure you'll change your mind after you think about it a little. I'm shure you'll choose another way.

Comment: Thanks @mazzy . I appreciated the answer.

Comment: I disagree. There are enough situations (such as an SSRS report parameter indicated in the OP screenshot) where you might want to select multiple enum values. If this was all net new development I might agree with you, but in the new world of extensions sometimes it's not so easy to "choose another way"

Comment: axapta has special framework  to convert enums to list of string to send it to SSRS. SSRS reports does not works with axapta enums. a `new world of extensions` sounds for me as `new world order` for the axapta :)